# How can I add a task (not a subtask) in RTM using only the keyboard?

Tags: remember-the-milk

The [keyboard shortcuts](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/?ctx=basics.basics.keyboard) page for Remember the Milk says to use `t` for adding a new item to the current list, but whenever I do so, it tries adding a subtask to the currently selected task instead...how can I add another task (not a subtask) in the list?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it adds a subtask rather than a new task is that you've selected an item from the list. First press `esc` to leave editing the task you're on, and then press `t` to add a new task.